# tracking a satellite

Tags: orbital-motion

The following article says that because the GOCE satellite has a polar orbit, it is impossible to track where it will land.

> "The satellite is one of the few satellites in a Polar Orbit. Consequently, it could land almost anywhere," Mark Hopkins, chair of the National Space Society's executive committee told FoxNews.com.

I was looking for an explanation based on the physics of the orbit, as I am not familiar with orbital mechanics.

http://www.foxnews.com/science/2013/11/08/track-europe-falling-2000-pound-satellite-in-real-time/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As satellites enter the atmosphere they start tumbling and the motion becomes chaotic and virtually impossible to predict. Because the deceleration of the satellite can't be predicted, the time it takes to hit the Earth and therefore the landing point can't be predicted either.

However for a satellite in an equatorial orbit the latitude is constant (i.e. 0 degrees) so it must land on the equator and therefore the latitude of the landing site is known. It's only the longitude that's uncertain. By contrast, in a polar orbit both the latitude and longitude change with time and both depend on the time taken for the satellite to fall. This means that neither the latitude nor the longitude of the landing site can be predicted. This is why the landing site could be *anywhere*.

Comment: "a satellite in an equatorial orbit - 99% of satellites" -Could you please give a reference? My impression was most satellites are launched far from the equator and are not moved to an equatorial orbit?

Comment: @akhmeteli: um, err, no I can't justify the 99% figure - though it doesn't change the point made in my answer. A quick Google suggests that many satellites have high inclinations so my 99% figure is certainly wrong. What the correct figure is I have no idea.